# Começando com Javascript

Tags: javascript

Peço desculpas se eu estiver postando no lugar errado
A questão é que estou começando no Javascript e não sei porquê esse script não funciona.

```html
<body>
  <p>Ganhe alguns meticais</p>
  <h2 id="cash">0</h2>
  <button onclick="jogar();">Jogar</button>
</body>

<script>
  function jogar() {
    var x = 1;
    while (x < 1000) {
      document.getElementById('cash').innerHTML = String(x);
      x = x + 10;
      if (x === 150) {
        break ();
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: o problema é que `break();` é um comando, não uma function, então precisa remover os parênteses: `break;`

Comment: Obrigado, era mesmo isso. Mas ainda o script só imprime um número, além de ir actualizando o #cash quando a variável x vei incrementando. Poderia me dar uma  luz?

Comment: seu script deve executar tão rápido que não dá pra perceber os valores mudando

Comment: Obrigado. Vou dar um jeito.

Comment: Pode colocar uma espera de 1 ou 2 segundos para cada mudança de número **x = x + 10;**. Pode usar `setInterval` ou `setTimeout()` para isso.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, é uma questão de entender como achar o erro; se você utilizar o navegador Chrome, por exemplo, você pode Inspecionar Elemento apertando Ctrl+Shift+I e acessar a aba Console para encontrar ocasionais problemas, principalmente de javascript.

Em seu código por exemplo, se acessar o Inspecionar > Console, vemos essa mensagem: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A mensagem diz "Não se espera (" ; ou seja, break não espera atributos de uma função. Se clicar no código, ele sinaliza exatamente onde é o problema 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A resposta para saber se um script JS funciona ou não é essa; boa sorte!